# android Error inflating class fragment when used with map fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, fragment

I'm trying to display a google map inside a fragment.The location is plotted correctly inside map but when i press back after mapping the location it shows another fragment and again press back showing an inflate exception.

Note:-
I have used only one activity and all other pages are fragments.

The below given is the code snippet for fragment(for displaying gmap)

```
   <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map_container"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

logcat:-

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.integral.loqal, PID: 15338                                                   
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #84: Binary XML file line #84: Error inflating class fragment
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                   at com.integral.loqal.Fragment.AddLocationFragment.onCreateView(AddLocationFragment.java:111)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:979)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1670)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManager.java:577)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #84: Error inflating class fragment
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                   at com.integral.loqal.Fragment.AddLocationFragment.onCreateView(AddLocationFragment.java:111) 
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974) 
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252) 
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:979) 
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1670) 
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManager.java:577) 
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617) 
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #84: Duplicate id 0x7f0b0119, tag null, or parent id 0x7f0b00bb with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2293)
                                                   at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:186)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                   at com.integral.loqal.Fragment.AddLocationFragment.onCreateView(AddLocationFragment.java:111) 
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974) 
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252) 
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:979) 
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1670) 
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManager.java:577) 
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617) 
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

java code:-

```
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.text.Editable;
 import android.text.TextWatcher;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.InflateException;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.MotionEvent;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.view.WindowManager;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.integral.loqal.CheckNetworkConnection;
import com.integral.loqal.Model.LocationItems;
import com.integral.loqal.PlaceDetailsJSONParser;
import com.integral.loqal.PlaceJSONParser;
import com.integral.loqal.R;
import com.integral.loqal.SessionManager;
import com.integral.loqal.Util.Utility;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
  import java.util.Locale;


   public class AddLocationFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapLongClickListener, OnMarkerDragListener {

          @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_google_map, container, false);

        mapTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapTextView);
        doneTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.doneTextView);



        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_container)).getMap();
        googleMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
        googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
        getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);


        atvPlaces = (AutoCompleteTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.searchLoc);

        atvPlaces.setThreshold(1);
        atvPlaces.showDropDown();



        latlong = latitude + "," + longitude;
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);


        marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoomLevel));

        backarrowImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.backArrowImageView);
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        int myInt = bundle.getInt("key", 0);

        if (myInt != 0 && myInt == 1) {
            mapTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


            backarrowImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();

            });
            doneTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Boolean inet = new CheckNetworkConnection().isNetworkAvailable(getContext());
                    if (inet == true) {
                        if (atvPlaces.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please choose a location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            updateLocation();
                            utility.registerUserResponse(jsonObject, UserLocationSet_URL,
                                    "UserLocationSet", getContext());
                        }

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                }
            });

        atvPlaces.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // Creating a DownloadTask to download Google Places matching "s"
                placesDownloadTask = new DownloadTask(PLACES);

                // Getting url to the Google Places Autocomplete api
                String url = getAutoCompleteUrl(s.toString());

                // Start downloading Google Places
                // This causes to execute doInBackground() of DownloadTask class
                placesDownloadTask.execute(url);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
        atvPlaces.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int index,
                                    long id) {

                ListView lv = (ListView) arg0;
                SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter) arg0.getAdapter();

                HashMap<String, String> hm = (HashMap<String, String>) adapter.getItem(index);

                // Creating a DownloadTask to download Places details of the selected place
                placeDetailsDownloadTask = new DownloadTask(PLACES_DETAILS);

                // Getting url to the Google Places details api
                String url = getPlaceDetailsUrl(hm.get("reference"));

                // Start downloading Google Place Details
                // This causes to execute doInBackground() of DownloadTask class
                placeDetailsDownloadTask.execute(url);

            }
        });

        return v;
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_container)).getMap();

    public String getAutoCompleteUrl(String place) {

        // Obtain browser key from https://code.google.com/apis/console
        String key = "key=";

        // place to be be searched
        String input = "input=" + place;

        // place type to be searched
        String types = "types=geocode";

        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = input + "&" + types + "&" + sensor + "&" + key;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/" + output + "?" + parameters;

        return url;
    }

    private String getPlaceDetailsUrl(String ref) {

        // Obtain browser key from https://code.google.com/apis/console
        String key = "key=";

        // reference of place
        String reference = "reference=" + ref;
        Log.d("TAg", reference);
        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = reference + "&" + sensor + "&" + key;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/" + output + "?" + parameters;

        return url;
    }

    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();
            System.out.println(data);
            String s[] = data.split(",");
            String pl = s[0];
            System.out.println(pl);
            br.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        } finally {
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg0) {


        if (marker != null) {
            marker.remove();
        }
        marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(
                        new LatLng(arg0.latitude,
                                arg0.longitude))
                .draggable(true).visible(true));


    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker arg0) {

        LatLng dragPosition = arg0.getPosition();
        latitude = dragPosition.latitude;
        longitude = dragPosition.longitude;
        dataloc = latitude + "," + longitude;

        String name = getCompleteAddressString(latitude, longitude);
        editor.putString("latitudeKey", Double.toString(latitude));
        editor.putString("longitudeKey", Double.toString(longitude));
        editor.putString("LocationName", name);
        editor.commit();

        latlong = latitude + "," + longitude;


        Log.i("info", "on drag end :" + latitude + " dragLong :" + longitude);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Marker Dragged..!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private int downloadType = 0;

        // Constructor
        public DownloadTask(int type) {
            this.downloadType = type;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            try {
                // Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            switch (downloadType) {
                case PLACES:
                    // Creating ParserTask for parsing Google Places
                    placesParserTask = new ParserTask(PLACES);

                    // Start parsing google places json data
                    // This causes to execute doInBackground() of ParserTask class
                    placesParserTask.execute(result);

                    break;

                case PLACES_DETAILS:
                    // Creating ParserTask for parsing Google Places
                    placeDetailsParserTask = new ParserTask(PLACES_DETAILS);

                    // Starting Parsing the JSON string
                    // This causes to execute doInBackground() of ParserTask class
                    placeDetailsParserTask.execute(result);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format
     */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String, String>>> {

        int parserType = 0;

        public ParserTask(int type) {
            this.parserType = type;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject;
            List<HashMap<String, String>> list = null;

            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

                switch (parserType) {
                    case PLACES:
              list = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);
                        break;
                    case PLACES_DETAILS:
                        PlaceDetailsJSONParser placeDetailsJsonParser = new PlaceDetailsJSONParser();
                        // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
                        list = placeDetailsJsonParser.parse(jObject);
                        System.out.println(list);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
            }
            return list;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
            try {
                switch (parserType) {
                    case PLACES:
                        String[] from = new String[]{"description"};
                        int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
                        if (getActivity() != null) {
                            adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), result, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, from, to);
                            atvPlaces.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }

                        break;
                    case PLACES_DETAILS:
                        HashMap<String, String> hm = result.get(0);

                        // Getting latitude from the parsed data
                        double newlatitude = Double.parseDouble(hm.get("lat"));

                        // Getting longitude from the parsed data
                        double newlongitude = Double.parseDouble(hm.get("lng"));
                        latlong = newlatitude + "," + newlongitude;
                        // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of the activity_main.xml
                        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_container);

                        // Getting GoogleMap from SupportMapFragment
                        googleMap = fm.getMap();

                        LatLng point = new LatLng(newlatitude, newlongitude);

                        CameraUpdate cameraPosition = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point);
                        CameraUpdate cameraZoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(15);
                        dataloc = latitude + "," + longitude;

                        // Utility.locationChange = latlong;


                        System.out.println(atvPlaces.getText().toString());
                        String s = atvPlaces.getText().toString();
                        String p[] = s.split(",");
                        String pla = p[0];



                        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(point, zoomLevel));
                        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
                        options.position(point);
                        options.title("Position");
                        options.snippet("Latitude:" + newlatitude + ",Longitude:" + newlongitude);
                        if (marker != null)
                            marker.remove();
                        // Adding the marker in the Google Map
                        marker = googleMap.addMarker(options);

                        break;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }







    public void onBackPressed() {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();

    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
    }
```

I dont know why it is showing the error.Can someone help me to find a solution?

Comment: where you add SupportMapFragment class in fragment?

Comment: please share java code...

Comment: I have shared java code.pls check it

Comment: can you please show me your header file and class extends what type of fragment add that code also

Comment: extends FragmentActivity instead of Fragment and change your code and try again

Answer (score 0):

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/map_container"
 class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Sorry not working...:(   getting error Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #84: Duplicate id 0x7f0b011a, tag null, or parent id 0x7f0b00bb with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout this link for  [GOOGLE MAP DOCUMENTATION](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map-with-marker)

**Activity Class**

```
 /**
 * init map fragment and get map async task
 */
private void initMapFragment() {
    AppUtils.showLog(TAG, "initMapFragment");
    try {
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**XML File**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mapwithmarker.MapsMarkerActivity" />
```